# Trying to save a value to my store using redux, and it does not seem to work

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to use redux to save information - I had previously gotten it to work, but I am trying to save to a different property name.

I have mostly been going off of this tutorial:

https://decembersoft.com/posts/redux-hero-part-1-a-hero-is-born-a-fun-introduction-to-redux-js/

My actions file:

```
 const Actions = {
    LEVEL_UP: 'LEVEL_UP',
    LEVEL_DOWN: 'LEVEL_DOWN',
    SAVE_COLOR: 'SAVE_COLOR'
  };

  // I also have action creators for levelUp and levelDown

  const saveColor  = (color) => ({
    type: Actions.SAVE_COLOR,
    payload: color
  });

  export default {levelUp, levelDown};

  export {saveColor};
```

In my reducer:

```
import general, {saveColor} from './reducers/general.js'

export default (history) => combineReducers({
  auth: auth,
  router: connectRouter(history),
  general: general,
  saveColor: saveColor,
})
```

In my component file:

```
import general from '../actions/general'
import saveColor from '../actions/general'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    general: state.general,
    saveColor: state.saveColor
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(saveColor, dispatch);
}

const Swatch = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Swatch1);
```

However when I try to use this command in the Swatch1 component, and I can confirm it gets here, no luck.

```
  render() {

    return (

  <ColorExtractor
    src={this.props.merchant.merchant.coverPhoto}
    getColors={colors => this.lightestColor(colors)}
  />

);
}
```

`this.lightestColor` has the following command:

```
this.props.saveColor(500);
```

I can absolutely confirm it gets to right before this saveColor() command - but the command itself doesn't seem to work.

How do I reliably get saveColor to work? I had it working when I just used general earlier.

EDIT: general.js from reducers:

```
import Actions from '../actions/general.js'

/*export default (state = 1, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LEVEL_UP':
        return state + 1;
      case 'LEVEL_DOWN':
          return state - 1;
      case 'SAVE_COLOR':
      return {color: action.payload}
    }
    return state;
  };*/

  export default (state = 1, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'SAVE_COLOR':
        return {color: action.payload}
      }
      return state;
    };

  //export {color};
```

I have both the original default export commented out, as well as what I've changed it to lately by making the color as default.

Comment: Can you share saveColor from ./reducers/general.js?

Comment: @ahz I added the content you wanted - I've commented out the default export and made the saveColor the default, though I can provide the original form if you have trouble deriving my original from it.

Comment: Basically I am having solid trouble understanding redux, and how I can possibly use two groups of action creators in one component without them being in separate files.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's an issuing storing the color or if it's retrieving it from the state?

Comment: My problem appears to be that I was saving the value to the same name as the function in mapStateToProps - once I changed saveColor = state.saveColor to something else it worked fine.